# Oracle Regular Expression-To match an exact word

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to search in a column named DESCRIPTION in a table which match the exact word ICE, Ice or ice. There may be other words before or after the keyword but it shouldn't be like Price, Mice, Nice. I want to take the help of Oracle regular expression as with normal `LIKE`, I am getting strings like Price, Mice etc as mentioned. I tried something like this `(DESCRIPTION LIKE '%ICE%' or DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Ice%')`. Please help.

Many Thanks.

Comment: You could use the upper() function to convert the description to upper case and then do UPPER(DESCRIPTION) LIKE '%ICE%'. For the exact word: have you tried spaces like '% ICE %'?

Comment: Or perhaps, `REGEXP_LIKE( DESCRIPTION, '([^[:alnum:]]|^)ice($|[^[:alnum:]])', 'i')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *regular expressions*, in case of Oracle it is `regexp_like`:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

```
select *
  from MyTable
 where regexp_like(DESCRIPTION, '^(.*\s+)?ice(\s+.*)?$', 'i')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  UPPER( description ) = 'ICE'
OR     UPPER( description ) LIKE 'ICE %'
OR     UPPER( description ) LIKE '% ICE'
OR     UPPER( description ) LIKE '% ICE %';
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( description, '(^|[^a-z])ice($|[^a-z])', 'i' )
```